how to mock a web component to be able to append it into other web component and use querySelector overit
Im trying to create unit tests for a angular project with Jest. Basically I have the test resolved with native html elements but I had to exchange them for web components and now the same code is not working.
Mainly I need to do the equivalence to this
let mockUlElement = document.createElement('ul');

For a web component call MurMenu (with tag <mur-menu>) and the same for a li tag with MurMenuItem (with tag <mur-menu>)
This doesnt work
let mockSixMenuElement = document.createElement('mur-menu');

This is my previous code for the whole test:
  it('handleArrowUpDownEvent', () => {
   let mockUlElement = document.createElement('ul');
   let mockLiElement = document.createElement('li');
   mockLiElement.focus = jest.fn();

  let aElement = document.createElement('a');
  aElement.click = jest.fn();
  mockLiElement.appendChild(aElement);
  mockUlElement.appendChild(mockLiElement);

  component.searchResults = new ElementRef(mockUlElement)
  component.selectedIndex = 1;

  jest.spyOn(component.searchResults.nativeElement, 
  'querySelector').mockReturnValue(mockUlElement);

   const eventArrowDown = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'ArrowDown' });

   component.searchFieldChanged = true;

   component.handleArrowUpDownEvent(eventArrowDown);    
   expect(component.selectedIndex).toEqual(0);

   component.handleArrowUpDownEvent(event);
   expect(jest.spyOn(mockLiElement, 'focus' )).toHaveBeenCalled();

 });

And this is my method:
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
 handleArrowUpDownEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (event.key === 'Escape') {
  this.sixHeader.setSearchOpenState(false);
  this.selectedIndex = 0;
 }

 if (this.searchFieldChanged === true) {
  this.murMenuElement = this.searchResults.nativeElement.querySelector('mur-menu');
  this.numberOfLiElements = this.murMenuElement ? this.murMenuElement.children.length : 0;
  this.murMenuItemElements = this.searchResults.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(
    'mur-menu > mur-menu-item',
  );

  for (let murMenuItem of this.murMenuItemElements) {
    murMenuItem.setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
  }

  if (event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
    this.selectedIndex = (this.selectedIndex + 1) % this.numberOfLiElements;
    }
  }
 }

